# How to insert sandbox Paypal return values into MySQL table using PHP Wordpress?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, paypal

I have done some transactions done by sandbox PayPal and got the transaction completed. After completing the transaction I have redirecting the URL to payments received page e.g **www.example.com/payments-recieved/**. And I have got some values in an array. The array receives the latest transaction details in an array as like this:

```
echo "<pre>";print_r($_REQUEST);

    Array
    (
        [tx] => 3RA54961H14867235
        [st] => Completed
        [amt] => 29.00
        [cc] => USD
        [cm] => 
        [item_number] => 
        [sig] => scLH/oMz+Q0+arHSabEPju068IFOcpsnu5Mb77AkvDJ0S9LO0ZOjvLx68ojre4Y2ZWFB/dWNz3RtzCzwiY5p5zI8uRhbPoBZRwlIOTU8XRqif9Ni2g/E/Wc4LL6gs0fpo618MN4pFnbina2sYi6fyzhOQoS5se+4vBywzhG0X0E=
    )
```

Now I have to insert these details into Wordpress table how we insert these details please let me know. Help me please guys.

Many Thanks in advance...

Comment: You want to insert which specific/every details in database table?

Comment: @BitsPlease dear we need to check if the transaction is completed then need to insert these values. [tx],[st],[amt],[cc],[item_number]

How we insert these values into wordpress table

Comment: I've updated my answer you can check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert using below query, where `order_details_table` is your table name, you can change it

```
if ( !empty( $_REQUEST) && $_REQUEST['st']=='completed' ){
    $wpdb->insert( 'order_details_table', array(
        'tx' => $_REQUEST['tx'], 
        'st' => $_REQUEST['st'],
        'amt' => $_REQUEST['amt'], 
        'cc' => $_REQUEST['cc'],
        'cm' => $_REQUEST['cm'], 
        'item_number' => $_REQUEST['item_number'], 
        'sig' => $_REQUEST['sig'],
    );
}
```

Comment: Not working, I have reloaded the tab but it does not insert the details into the table. This is my table columns please check is there anything wrong. global $wpdb; //global query variable
 if ( !empty( $_REQUEST) && $_REQUEST['st']=='completed' ){
    $wpdb->insert( 'wp_paypal_payments_tracking', array(
        'transaction_id' => $_REQUEST['tx'], 
        'st' => $_REQUEST['st'],
        'amount' => $_REQUEST['amt'], 
        'currency_type' => $_REQUEST['cc'],
        'item_number' => $_REQUEST['item_number'], 
        );
    echo "Payment Done Successfully"; 
}

Comment: no errors. Nothing happens. No record in the table.  Please help?

Comment: I have done a new transaction but nothing happens. No data will be going to wordpress table. Table is blank.

Comment: can you please check by enabling ERROR reporting on and check again? Deginitely there will be small typo or something like that

Comment: How to enable, I don't know will you help?

Comment: are you there mate, will you help me out

Answer (score 0):

Remeber that this redirection page may not necessarily be like the other wordpress files. You can have it like normal PHP file and it would still work.

```
$response = json_encode($_REQUEST);
if($respone->st == "completed")
{
    $sql = "insert into yourtable (Columns) values (values);
    //Format the above line and do normal way of sql execution
}
else
{
  //do whatever you want
}
//you can still display the status in this page
```

Comment: dear sir but I want this in wordpress only. How we can achieve this one.